# Is my solution proper proof for theese two constants making the piecewise function continuous?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

If we have the piecewise defined function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2+ax+b &,\ x\le0 \\
e^x(x+1) &,\ x> 0
\end{cases}$$

#### Solution:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x) = f(0) \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}\left(x^2+ax+b\right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(e^x(x+1)\right) \iff b = 1$$

Now we have the function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2+ax+1 &,\ x\le 0 \\
e^x(x+1) &,\ x > 0
\end{cases}$$

*Now is the part I'm a bit unsure of*

When $x=0$ we have that $f'(0^-) = a = f'(0^+)=0 \iff a = 0$

$\therefore$ The function is continuous **iff** $a=0\land b=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need $b=1$ -- the derivatives don't need to match up for $f$ to be merely *continuous*.

If you want $f$ to be *differentiable* at $0$ what you need is not $a=0$ but $a=2$.

Comment: How can this be shown? I'm having a hard time accepting that even after I've tried both high and low values of $a$ in Mathematica while plotting them.

Comment: @XMLParsing: Are you sure you're plotting it correctly? Here's a [Wolfram Alpha plot for a=10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=piecewise%28{{x%5e2%2B10x%2B1%2Cx%3C%3D0}%2C{e%5ex%28x%2B1%29%2Cx%3E0}}%29)

Comment: Yes, that's how I plot them. And that's why I'm skeptical, the sudden change of slope value at $x=0$. It reminds me of the $abs$ function which isn't able to be derived at it's turning point.

Comment: @XMLParsing: Yes, the slope changes, so what? _Continuity_ doesn't care about that, and $|x|$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made the mistake my book warned me about. **Differentiable function $\implies$ Continuity** not the other way around. Thanks. How did you find the value for $a = 2$?

Comment: @XMLParsing: I differentiated $e^x(x+1)$ and got $e^x(x+2)$ which is $2$ at $0$. And the slope for $x^2+ax+b$ at $0$ is $a$, so for that to be $2$ we must have $a=2$.